# Mantener session en dos routers

Tags: javascript, express

Tengo 2 routers, para el ejemplo

**router1**

```
app.post('/consultas', function (req, res) {

    req.session.nombre = 'administrador';
   console.log('prueba',req.session.nombre); // ahi la session se guarda bien
});
```

**router2**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('recuperar session   ', req.session);// sale undefined
}
```

como puedo obtener la session en los dos router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi con cookieSession

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(cookieSession({
                    name: 'session'
                    , secret: randomstring.generate()
                    , httpOnly: true
                    , maxAge: 30 * 60 * 1000
                    , secure: false
                    , overwrite: false
              }));


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/session', session);
```

**Nota**: debe ser en ese orden para que los routes obtengan la session del server.

La utilizacion se puede usar asi(no hace falta `middlewares`), guardando en la variable session

```
app.post('/consultas', function (req, res) {

    req.session.nombre = 'administrador';
   console.log('prueba',req.session.nombre); // ahi la session se guarda bien
});
```

y en los demas routes la variable session esta disponible para usarlo

Answer (score 1):

viendo tu logica podrias guardar la session en un middleware y en las dos rutas aplicales el middleware ya creado ahi obtendras los datos guardados del usuario
asi podras meter tu middleware en tu ruta

```
function mymiddleware(req,res,next){
  req.session.nombre='MiNOMBRE';
}
```

**req.session.nombre** a q todas las petidiciones q utilisen este middleware tendran acceso al **req.session.nombre**

```
app.get('/miroute1',mymiddleware,(req,res) => {
      console.log(req.session.nombre);
         }
app.get('/miroute2',mymiddleware,(req,res) => {
      console.log(req.session.nombre);
         }
```

un poco mas explicado aqui

de como crear un middleware

[https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html][1]

de como usarlos

[https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html][1]

Comment: lo probe con app.get('/miroute2',mymiddleware,(req,res) => {    pero jamas entra